# Can I change the resolution of a jpg image in Java?

Tags: java, jpeg, image-resizing

I have some .jpg's that I'm displaying in a panel. Unfortunately they're all about 1500x1125 pixels, which is way too big for what I'm going for. Is there a programmatic way to change the resolution of these .jpg's?

Comment: Check this out http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/

Comment: @Tom, that worked perfectly, thank you very much! Make it an answer and you've got yourself a check mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can scale an image using `Graphics2D` methods (from `java.awt`). This [tutorial at mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/) explains it in depth.

Answer (score 3):

Load it as an ImageIcon and this'll do the trick:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public static ImageIcon resizeImageIcon( ImageIcon imageIcon , Integer width , Integer height )
{
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage( width , height , BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT );

    Graphics2D graphics2D = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    graphics2D.drawImage( imageIcon.getImage() , 0 , 0 , width , height , null );
    graphics2D.dispose();

    return new ImageIcon( bufferedImage , imageIcon.getDescription() );
}
```

Comment: Oh man, I WAS going to check tom off as an answer, but I AM already using ImageIcon, so this might be more what I need. STAND BY FOR FUTURE EXCITING UPDATES!

Comment: I'm getting an "error: cannot find symbol" on this line
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage( width , height , BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
It points to the BufferedImage part in the build output window.

Comment: I'm not sure, it compiles fine on mine. What IDE are you using?

Comment: JCreator LE. Is there some import I'm missing?

Comment: I added the imports to the answer.

Comment: Great. Not getting build errors anymore! But... it's not doing anything. I need to make sure I'm doing this right... I set the ImageIcon line:   'ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("...\\J02406-TOP.jpg");'  Then call resizeImageIcon?  'resizeImageIcon(icon, 500, 400);'

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
private BufferedImage getScaledImage(Image srcImg, int w, int h) {
    BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g2.dispose();
    return resizedImg;
}
```